# Morrey's inequality for Sobolev spaces of fractional order

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis, holder-spaces

Let $H^s(\mathbb T)$, where $s\in\mathbb R$,  be the space of $2\pi$-periodic functions, $u(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\hat u_k\,\mathrm{e}^{ikx}$, such that 
$$
\|u\|_{H^s}^2=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}(1+k^2)^{s}\lvert \hat u_k\rvert^2<\infty.
$$
Assume now that $s\in \big(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\big)$. Is it true that there exist a constant $c=c_s$, such that
$$
\lvert u(x)-u(y)\rvert\le c \|u\|_{H^s}\lvert x-y\rvert^{s-\frac{1}{2}}?
$$
If $s=1$, then the above is a special case of the the celebrated Morrey's inequality.

Reference would be welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same approach as in [Decay of Fourier Coefficients implies Holder Continuity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/933879) works.  The starting point is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$
|u(x)-u(y)|^2
=\left(\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} (1+k^2)^{s/2}\hat u_k \ \frac{|e^{ikx}-e^{iky}|}{(1+k^2)^{s/2}}\right)^2 \\ \le 
 \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} (1+k^2)^s|\hat u_k|^2 \ \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{|e^{ikx}-e^{iky}|^2 }{(1+k^2)^s} \\= \|u\|_{H^s}^2 \sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} \frac{|e^{ikx}-e^{iky}|^2 }{(1+k^2)^s}
$$

It remains to estimate the last sum by a multiple of $|x-y|^{2s-1}$. To do this, split it into ranges $|k|\le M$ and $|k|>M$ where 
  $M=\pi/|x-y|$.

#### Low frequencies

Since $|e^{ikx}-e^{iky}|^2\le k^2|x-y|^2$, we get at most 
$$
|x-y|^2 \sum_{|k|\le M} \frac{k^2}{(1+k^2)^s}
\le C|x-y|^2 M^{3-2s} = C'|x-y|^{2s-1}
$$

#### High frequencies

Since $|e^{ikx}-e^{iky}|^2\le 4$, we get at most 
$$
\sum_{|k|> M} \frac{4}{(1+k^2)^s}
\le CM^{1-2s} = C'|x-y|^{2s-1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

This should hold.

**Lemma**

Define
$$
P_j f (x) = \sum_{\sigma = \pm 1, k=2^j}^{2^{j+1}} \hat{f}(\sigma k) e^{2\pi i \sigma k x}.
$$
If $\lvert f \rvert \leq 1$, then $f \in C^\alpha(\mathbb{T})$ for $0 < \alpha < 1$ iff
$$
\sup_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} 2^{j\alpha} \| P_j f \|_\infty \leq A
$$
for some $A$, and the smallest such $A$ is comparable to the $\alpha$-Holder norm of $f$.

Let $\alpha = s - 1/2$. By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$
\| P_j u \|_\infty \lesssim \| u \|_{H^s} \left( \sum_{k=2^j}^{2^{j+1}} (1 +k^2)^{-s} \right)^{1/2} \lesssim  \| u \|_{H^s}2^{-j \alpha}.
$$
Thus if the lemma holds, the desired statement holds.

There is a proof of the lemma in the continuum case in Schlag and Muscalu's *Classical and Multilinear Harmonic Analysis*, Vol 1, section 8.3.1, page 205. Looking over the proof, it seems the circle case should also hold, and the proof may even simplify a bit. Admittedly, I have not delved into the details.

Comment: In the corresponding MO question, [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/241949/46135) has been added. This is the same as my approach, but written more clearly and with more detail as to show how Littlewood-Paley theory comes in.